# What "Chatter" features work with Napili Salesforce Community Template?

Tags: community, chatter, customer-community, napili

I've setup a Salesforce Community using the Napili template. Through lots of trial and error, I got the topics, and articles to show but I cannot seem to figure out how to get any "Chatter" feature to work in the community.

[The documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_enable_integrations.htm) is just not complete and/or too high level. It says all kinds of stuff about enabling all these wonderful features for your community in just a few steps, but apparently fails to mention that nearly none of them work with Napili.

[This article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/networks_enable_chatter_questions.htm) suggests that you can enable the "Chatter Questions" feature in your Napili template by following these 4 easy steps:

1. From Setup, enter Publisher Layouts in the Quick Find box, then select Publisher Layouts.
2. Click Edit next to the global publisher layout.
3. Drag the Question action from the palette to the global publisher layout. If the Question action already appears in the layout, drag it to the location where you want it.
4. Click Save.

I did this, and nothing happened. When I click the "Ask A Question" button, my only open is "Contact Support":

[image]

Searching the web for answers comes up empty. When I contact Salesforce Support, they tell me templates is custom development and not covered by our support agreement (not that I would have gotten a useful answer from Salesforce support anyways).

I realize that our Salesforce org will be soon be upgraded to Spring 16 and that should open up a lot more Chatter features, but it just blows my mind that getting anything resembling Chatter to work with the Napili template has so far been a waste of time.

Has anyone gotten Chatter [Answers/Questions/Anything] working on the Napili template and if so, what is required to do so?

Comment: It just works for me .Ask a Question button brings a POP up and works .Are you missing anything .In my org it was enabled by default

Comment: Mohith, thanks for the reply. I get the popup but my only option is Contact Support per the pic I just posted on my question.

Comment: What do you mean by only option ?Can you add screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Options that we see in the Select Post Destination is based on the Navigational Topics .

You will need to add some Navigational Topics to see the Options there .

Take a look at screenshot from one my sample orgs

[image]

Here is good old [blog](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2014/11/learn-how-to-use-salesforce-communities.html) from me on how to set these

Comment: @Swisher Sweet...you owe me lot I guess :)

Comment: Yes! You appear to be the Salesforce Community Genius around here... ;)